# How to re-render canvasjs chart with animation?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, canvasjs

So far I've been successfully updating the data for the my chart following the guide in this [link](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/).

However, how can do re-render it but with the same animation when it was first rendered?

Comment: I don't think we have a canvasjs guru here on SO yet, and the one canvasjs question about dynamic charts has gone unanswered.  I suspect you'll have to work this one out yourself. Then perhaps you'll come back as the canvasjs guru! Anyway, good luck with your project. :-)

Comment: Yeah sadly enough. My current ugly workaround is to reinstantiate the chart every time I update just to achieve that animation effect. haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somehow a hack and I know it shouldn't be this way but the only solution I found was to reinitialize the creation of the chart just to achieve that animation.

Comment: Upvoted for providing solution and a followup. It may be something you can discuss with the [author of canvasjs](https://github.com/eyamil/Canvas-JS/issues), to see if it can be implemented (if not already in some obscure way).