# How to animate dynamic updates in CanvasJS using React functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, canvasjs

Using React functional components, I have not been able to find a way to animate my chart with dynamic data received asynchronously. The sandbox below illustrates the problem with a timer simulating the asynchronous read.

https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-column-chart-in-react-canvasjs-0gfv6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

When running the example code, you should see 5 vertical bars of increasing heights animate.  Then, after 5 seconds, it switches immediately to 4 bars of descending heights. I am looking to have that update animate.

Here is some reference information I've reviewed:
[CanvasJS React Demos](https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/): many of which animate on initial draw, but I couldn't find one that animates with dynamic data loaded after the initial render.

[Chart using JSON Data](https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/json-data-api-ajax-chart/) is an demo that has dynamic data, but doesn't animate.

Reviewing the CanvasJS forum, I found a couple links, but none that address React functional components

[Vishwas from Team Canvas](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/how-to-re-render-with-animation/) said:

> To update dataPoints dynamically and to animate chart, you can instantiate the chart, update dataPoints via chart-options and then call chart.render as shown in this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk25g1mr/).

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Animation test"
  },
  animationEnabled: true,  
  data: [{
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: []
  }]
});

chart.options.data[0].dataPoints =  [{ label: "Apple", y: 658 },
                                     { label: "Orange", y: 200 },
                                     { label: "Banana", y: 900 }];
chart.render();
```

This sample is pure JS, but I tried to adapt the principle to my React functional component.  To better comport with React best practices, I incorporated the `useState` hook for storing the data and the `useEffect` hook to handle the fetch. But, alas, I couldn't get my sandbox to animate with the dynamic data.

I think the problem is that CanvasJS expects to animate only on the first render, as stated by [Sanjoy in the CanvasJS forum on 7/19/2016](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/updated-data-is-not-animated/).

I found [this SO question from Jan 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147817/how-to-re-render-canvasjs-chart-with-animation) that suggests:

> My current ugly workaround is to reinstantiate the chart every time I
>   update just to achieve that animation effect.

I'm hopeful that the situation has improved in the last four years, but if this hack is still the best/only way to go, I need some guidance on how to *reinstantiate the chart every time* using a React functional component.

Comment: You need to dispose (destroy) react chart component and they re create it. To do that you will need one root App class then created child component (chrts). This is `only way` (with react) not for this case but for manu others.In your case example i see procedural way of using react.  Look at https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/react-vs-typescript-starter

Answer (score 1):

To force a remount of a component pass a different `key` when you want to remount the component

```js
<CanvasJSChart
  key={dataPoints.toString()} // force a remount when `dataPoints` change
  containerProps={containerProps}
  options={options}
  onRef={ref => (chart.current = ref)}
/>
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-animate-canvasjs-update-vwgsb)

Answer (score -1):

Both examples works fine.

You can always animate chars with some kind of calling. I use in this case setInterval.

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
 
 var chart;
 
window.onload = function () {

  chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
   title: {
     text: "Animation test"
   },
   animationEnabled: true,  
   data: [{
     type: "column",
     dataPoints: []
   }]
 });

 chart.options.data[0].dataPoints =  [{ label: "Apple", y: 0 },
                                     { label: "Orange", y: 0 },
                                     { label: "Banana", y: 0 }];
 chart.render();

}

var max = 0;
var s = {c: 0, i: 0};
function ANIMATE() {
 
    if (typeof chart === 'undefined') return;
    
    chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    
      if (index == s.i) {
         array[index].y += 3;
         s.c++;
      }
      
      if (s.c > 12) {
        s.i++;
        s.c = 0;
        if (s.i == 15) { s.i = 0}
      }
      
    
    });
    
    if (max < 12) {
    chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.push({label: "apple" + Math.random(), y: 1 + Math.random() * 10});
     max++;
    }
    
   chart.render()
}


setInterval(function(){
 ANIMATE()
}, 1)

</script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: My question was about leveraging the animation capabilities built into CanvasJS via the `animationEnabled` property within a React functional component.  This answer does not address the question.

Please refer to this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-column-chart-in-react-canvasjs-0gfv6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score -1):

I found a partial answer. Full executing code is in [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/canvasjs-update-uuolq), but the critical bit is to delay the initial render of the chart until a state variable indicates that the data is available:

```
  return (
<div className="App">
  {!initialized ? (
    <h1> Loading...</h1>
  ) : (
    <CanvasJSChart containerProps={containerProps} options={options} />
  )}
</div>
```

);

This is only a partial solution because subsequent data updates still do not animate.